# What is the best practice to make a time delay for multiple programs in Python?

Tags: python, bash, time, delay

I know

```
time.sleep(t)
```

makes the program sleep for t seconds, but my issue here is that I have multiple bash shells runnung the same program with different parameters. For example, first shell will loop with t=30, second shell with t=60, and third shell with t=180. Three programs are intended to run in its own timezone, the first one loops every 30 seconds, the second one loops every 60 seconds, and the third one loops every 180 seconds. But it seems like they interfere each other, creating much longer delay for each program.

So what I figured out is using

```
os.system("sleep t")
```

instead of time.sleep, and it seems to work fine.

But I'm still very skeptical that this is the best practice to make delay in time. What would be the best practice?

Thanks you.

Comment: It seems odd that individual distinct programs would affect execution of each other unless they are using so many resources as to slow the whole system down. Could you elaborate on why you think they interact with each other as well as how they are invoked to begin running? A short listing of code may also be helpful.

Comment: `time.sleep` just sleeps. You shouldn't be seeing this strange difference. There has to be something else going on.

Comment: Also note that "sleep t" doesnt really do a sleep as t is a sting "t" and not the variable t.